# Trying to remove my restart button once it is game over

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, enumerate

I am trying to get rid of the restart button once the player has lost 5 lives and it is GAMEOVER I have created. This code is not doing it for me, can anyone help me understand why?

```
func loseALife(){
    if lives == 0 {
        enumerateChildNodes(withName: "Restart", using: ({
            (node, error) in
                self.removeAllActions()
        })

        runGameOver()
    }
}
```

This is the function for the restart button

```
func createButton() {
    restartButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "restart")
    restartButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    restartButton.zPosition = 6
    restartButton.setScale(0.5)
    restartButton.name = "Restart"
    self.addChild(restartButton)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `self.removeAllActions()` use

```
node.removeFromParent()
```

You are using `self` which in this case refers to the GameScene and `removeAllActions` which only applies to game elements that currently have actions running. The variable `node` is from each iteration of `enumerateChildNodes` and is a direct reference to the button.

Comment: Ill try it now. Thanks heaps!